# <Spring:Message> Auto-generate Unique Key

Tags: spring, spring-messaging

I am working with a Spring MVC project. We are using the  tags for handling our bilingual requirements. Currently we have two resource files, English and French. I am trying to back away from hard-coding these files and instead populate new keys and values from the database. Checking existing and adding new keys is not difficult. I was wondering if there was a way to have the system create new unique keys. I could just have them built off a special header and an auto-increasing value, but I would rather use a built in feature to handle it. Is there such a feature? If so, could you provide a link on documentation on using it?

Answer (score 1):

Some data bases have it as a built in feature, some don't. You should really consult the docs of the DB you're using. It's not a Spring feature.

You can also use UUID which technically is globally unique . . . . The `...` simply means there are *edge cases*, but for your requirement I believe it would be more then reliable.

Comment: I do not want the database doing it as it does not know what keys already exist in the properties files in the application and I do not feel like copying them.